# VBA to copy entire cell values to clipboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, microsoft-excel-2007, clipboard

```
Sub Test()
    Dim copycell As DataObject
    Dim ws As Workbook
    Dim strText As String
    Set ws = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Desktop\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx")
    strText = ws.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
MsgBox strText
   With New MSForms.DataObject
    .SetText strText
    .PutInClipboard
End With
End Sub
```

scenario is to copy the entire excel value to clipboard the above code will copy only cell A1 value can anyone update the code so that it will copy all the datas in excel to clipboard

Comment: Unclear. Does you fetch cell value partially now?

Comment: no i want the entire value of the excel file to clipboard

Comment: You want all values from all cells from all sheets? It is impossible. Or all values from all cells from one sheet? Select them, then copy - 2-dimensional array will be placed into clipboard. Or you want to iterate all cells one-by-one? use ForEach.

Comment: can u pls update the code as 2dimensional array

Comment: To array variable: `Dim wholedata(): wholedata=ws.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Value`. To clipboard: `ws.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy`.

Comment: i tried usedrange.copy but the output is only true

Comment: Copy method of Range object copies selected range into clipboard (if Destination parameter is not set). *output is only true* This means the range was copied to clipboard successfully.

Comment: I give you the whole code. I'd recommend you to formulate the task rather the way you decide to use for to solve it.

Comment: ok akina pls send me the whole code

Comment: Based on the comments you've posted indicating you want to copy entire spreadsheet to the clipboard, your question is probably suffering from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) (also see the [XY problem on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445)). You really do not want to copy the entire spreadsheet to the clipboard. What exactly is your end goal here?

Comment: *copy the entire excel value* ... What value?

Comment: ctrl+a followed by ctrl+c will copy the excel value right that value i want

Comment: The word value is singular, i.e. only one cell. It sounds like what you want is to copy all of the cells in the worksheet. You need to make your question say precisely that.

Comment: yes bro thats the case

Comment: Despite being asked MULTIPLE times to make your question (not your comments) clear, you have still failed to do it. We need the questions to be clear and complete and yours is still not, as you have noted several times.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
strText = ws.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Needs to be changed to:

```
strText = ws.Sheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.Value
```

The reference made by `Range("A1")` is a fixed reference to cell A1. Using `ActiveCell` instead references the currently selected cell.

Comment: object doesnt support this property or method as error popup

Comment: is there anyother way to copy the entire content of the excel file

Comment: Huh? That's not what you ask in the question. Make your question all what you intend to ask. Don't ask something different in the comments.

Comment: my scenario is to copy the entire excel value to clipboard the above code will copy only cell A1 value

Comment: Your question says *I want the entire cell value* but now you say you want the entire Excel file. You **must** fix your question before you will get an answer. (By the way, you probably mean you want the contents of the entire worksheet, *not* the entire file, i.e. workbook). Heads up though... You probably can't copy the entire worksheet to the clipboard. It's too big.

Comment: yes consider i am having sheet1 in the excel file so i want to copy all the values of sheet1 to clipboard

Comment: I will not post further comments until you edit your question as I have asked twice.

Comment: its edited bro please check